# Timeout.InfiniteTimespan in .Net 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, timer, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I actually do know that `Timeout.InfiniteTimespan` does not exist in .NET 4.0.

Noticed, there's also `Timeout.Infinite` which does exist in .NET 4.0

I am calling those two methods:

```
// the Change-Method
public bool Change(
    TimeSpan dueTime,
    TimeSpan period
)

// the Constructor of Timer
public Timer(
    TimerCallback callback,
    Object state,
    TimeSpan dueTime,
    TimeSpan period
)
```

in some cases, the `dueTime` Parameter needs to be infinite, which means the Event is not fired. I know I could simply use an other overload, but I feel like something has to be more simple.

I already tried using `new TimeSpan(0, 0, -1)` or `new TimeSpan(-1)` as dueTime. *But that throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` pointing to the `dueTime` Parameter.

**Is it somehow possible to create a literal working like the `Timeout.InfiniteTimespan` from .NET 4.5 ?**

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`TimeOut.InfiniteTimeSpan` in [`TimeOut` class is defined](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timeout.cs,18) as:

```
public static readonly TimeSpan InfiniteTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, Timeout.Infinite);
```

*Where `Timeout.Infinite` is set to `-1`*,so it is passing **`-1` value for milliseconds** part.

You can do:

```
TimeSpan InfiniteTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, -1);
```

Answer (score 17):

Infinite timespan is nothing but `TimeSpan` with milliseconds set to `-1`

So, you can just do

```
TimeSpan infinite = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your model supports events where the "due" time does not exist, then setting it to infinity to indicate that seems wrong.  Why not make the parameter nullable?

Comment: It seems like there was a missunderstanding.. the subject is the `System.Threading.Timer`

Comment: Ah, that wasn't specified.  I think there's something wrong with your business logic, however - if the event never fires, then why bother putting it into the timer?

Comment: You are right, it wasnt specified. Allthough dont worry :)... it does fire when it should and the timer is never initialized, stopped and remaining unused.