# Azure App Configuration - Disable Refresh - SetCacheExpiration

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-configuration

I am using Azure App Configuration for loading config into my Azure Functions. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/data.appconfiguration-readme?view=azure-dotnet-preview

I am using a `free` plan, and I ran into request throttled issue because of the default 30 seconds cache expiration. [at least I believe so]

To prevent this I used `SetCacheExpiration` as follow,

```
 builder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
            {
                options.Connect(this.Values.AppConfigConnectionString)
                    .ConfigureRefresh(refresh =>
                    {
                        // default is 30 seconds
                        refresh.SetCacheExpiration(TimeSpan.FromDays(10));
                    });
                options.Select(keyFilter: KeyFilter.Any, labelFilter: this.Values.Env);
            });
```

I do not need to refresh this key-value, because it's not going to change frequently. 
So my question is, is it possible to disable this cache expiration?

If so, how? If not, what should be the workaround?

TIA,
Kiran.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are not calling [RefreshAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.azureappconfiguration.iconfigurationrefresher.refreshasync?view=azure-dotnet-preview) anywhere this should not matter. If you are not calling RefreshAsync then there must be another reason the limit was hit. My guess would be that multiple configuration builders are being built.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `Infinite Timespan`:

```cs
public static readonly TimeSpan InfiniteTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, Timeout.Infinite);
```

Taken from this question [Timeout.InfiniteTimespan in .Net 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30327999/timeout-infinitetimespan-in-net-4-0).