# HttpClient.Timeout = System.Threading.Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan throwing exception, also the exception is null

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, dotnet-httpclient, webapi

```
if(isLongRunning && null != Client && Client.Timeout != System.Threading.Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan)
{
    Client.Timeout = System.Threading.Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;
}
```

[screen shot of the code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubbtv.png)

assigning InfiniteTimeSpan to HttpClient.Timeout giving me an exception that I can't see.
exception says null, I wonder if there is a intermedia level I can see what this exception is?

[Screenshot of the null execption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5TTJ.png)

Anyone knows why this would blow up?

Comment: Could you see exceptions in the console's output ?

Comment: I went to Output Debug, stepping through where the exception happened, I didn't see anything except bunch of threads started and closed

Comment: You  could try to look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/30328117/10768653.